# Junit Test failed

Tags: sql, jdbc

In the following code the query which I used is correct I checked it in the sql server but the test is failing in eclipse what am I doing wrong?

```
    public int ShipYearLaunched(Connection connection, String ship) throws 
    SQLException {
    String a="select Launched from Ships where name=?";
    PreparedStatement st=connection.prepareStatement(a);
    st.setString(1, ship);
    ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    int count = rs.getInt("c");
    return count; 
}
```

This is what its showing in the Failure Trace.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 2 is out of range.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:940)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:954)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setString(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1532)
    at jdbc.JDBC.MostShipsSunkInBattle(JDBC.java:43)
    at jdbc.JDBC_Test.TestNumShipsSunkInBattle(JDBC_Test.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: What is the message?  That would help debug it. Are you printing any stack traces that come up?  Or do you swallow exceptions with an empty catch block?

Comment: where is "c" rs.getInt("c"); in your select?

Comment: I dont know about it.

Comment: I don't understand, it is in your code. What do you want to do when you do rs.getInt("c"); ? Is the query correct or do you want to do some sort of count(*)?

Comment: You are selecting a column named `Launched` but you are trying to get a value from a column named `c` - why do you expect a column named `c` in that result?

Comment: According the the stacktrace, the error occurs in method `MostShipsSunkInBattle`, while the code shown is of method `ShipYearLaunched`. Please show the right code.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to tell what your problem is from the code and the message.  It would help if you'd post the creation SQL for the table.

I don't like what I see in your SQL.  I'd say it should be the SHIP table, not plural.

You aren't following Java coding standards.

You don't close your resources in method scope.

I would write something more like this:

```
    private static final String SELECT_YEAR_LAUNCHED_SQL = "select yearLaunched from Ship where name = ?";


    public int getShipYearLaunched(Connection connection, String shipName) throws SQLException {
        int yearLaunched = 0;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null; 
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_LAUNCHED_SQL);
            st.setString(1, ship);
            rs = st.executeQuery();
            // Is there more than one row for a given ship name?  If yes, you should get a List<Integer> and append the value returned to the List
            while (rs.hasNext()) {
                yearLaunched = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        } finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }
        return yearLaunched; 
    }
```